# Combining attributes in a class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I have the following custom class

```
class rollingD {
 private String settDate;
    private String publishingPeriodCommencingTime;
    private String fuelTypeGeneration;

    public String getSettDate() {
        return settDate;
    }

    public void setSettDate(String settDate) {
        this.settDate = settDate;
    }

    public String getPublishingPeriodCommencingTime() {
        return publishingPeriodCommencingTime;
    }

    public void setPublishingPeriodCommencingTime(String publishingPeriodCommencingTime) {
        this.publishingPeriodCommencingTime = publishingPeriodCommencingTime ;
    }

    public String getFuelTypeGeneration() {
        return fuelTypeGeneration;
    }

    public void setFuelTypeGeneration(String fuelTypeGeneration) {
        this.fuelTypeGeneration = fuelTypeGeneration;
    }

    @Override
 public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s,%s,%s",
                             settDate,
                             publishingPeriodCommencingTime,
                             fuelTypeGeneration);



 }}
```

The items add to my array list as below

```
ArrayList<rollingD> aList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The attributes

```
settDate
and 
publishingPeriodCommencingTime
```

are separate entities

```
01/04/2020
and 
21:34:26
```

What i would like to do is within my class i want to combine my attributes before adding them to the array list

so i would end up with

```
01/04/2020 21:34:26
```

as a single attribute

I would therefore only have 2 attributes in my arraylist which i can then sort etc

Can someone provide assistance please.

I have tried streaming a map afterwards and combining the streams after but i realised that is not an ideal solution as i need to then work with the arraylist further down the line and ideally with datetimestamp and the value as my only two items

This is the code for parsing the API

```
      while(parser.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent event = parser.nextEvent();

    switch(event.getEventType()) {

    case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
    StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
    String qName = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("settDate")) {
       rD = new rollingD(null,null,null);
    bMarks = true;


    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("publishingPeriodCommencingTime")) {
    bLastName = true;

    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("fuelTypeGeneration")) {
    bNickName = true;
    aList.add(rD);

    }

    break;

    case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
    Characters characters = event.asCharacters();
    if(bMarks) {

  //  System.out.println("settDate: " + characters.getData());
    rD.getTimeStamp(characters.getData(),null,null);
    bMarks = false;

    }
    if(bLastName) {
  //  System.out.println("publishingPeriodCommencingTime: " + characters.getData());
    rD.getTimeStamp(null,characters.getData(),null);

    bLastName = false;
    }
    if(bNickName) {
   // System.out.println("fuelTypeGeneration: " + characters.getData());
    rD.getTimeStamp(null,null,characters.getData());
    bNickName = false;
    }



    break;

    case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
    EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();





//List<String> namesList = aList.stream()
//.map(x->x.getSettDate()+" "+ x.getPublishingPeriodCommencingTime()+","+ x.getFuelTypeGeneration())
//.collect(Collectors.toList());

//Collections.sort(namesList);
//
//for (String name : namesList) {
//System.out.println(name);
//}








    if(endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

    System.out.println();
    }
    break;
    } 
    }
```

Comment: You could have a read only property that returns a new string (settDate + publishingPeriodCommencingTime). This would allow you to sort using thos one property. It might also be worth looking at uaing DateTime to store this rather than strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
class RollingD {
    private String settDate;
    private String publishingPeriodCommencingTime;
    private String fuelTypeGeneration;
    private String timeStamp;

    public RollingD(String settDate, String publishingPeriodCommencingTime, String fuelTypeGeneration) {
        this.settDate = settDate;
        this.publishingPeriodCommencingTime = publishingPeriodCommencingTime;
        this.fuelTypeGeneration = fuelTypeGeneration;
        timeStamp = settDate != null && publishingPeriodCommencingTime != null && !settDate.isEmpty()
                && !publishingPeriodCommencingTime.isEmpty() ? settDate + " " + publishingPeriodCommencingTime : "";
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return settDate != null && publishingPeriodCommencingTime != null && !settDate.isEmpty()
                && !publishingPeriodCommencingTime.isEmpty() ? settDate + " " + publishingPeriodCommencingTime : "";

    }

    // ..Do not create any setter for timeStamp
    // ..Other getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RollingD [settDate=" + settDate + ", publishingPeriodCommencingTime=" + publishingPeriodCommencingTime
                + ", fuelTypeGeneration=" + fuelTypeGeneration + ", timeStamp=" + timeStamp + "]";
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RollingD rd1 = new RollingD("", "", "G");
        System.out.println(rd1);
        RollingD rd2 = new RollingD("01/04/2020", "", "G");
        System.out.println(rd2);
        RollingD rd3 = new RollingD("", "21:34:26", "G");
        System.out.println(rd3);
        RollingD rd4 = new RollingD("01/04/2020", "21:34:26", "G");
        System.out.println(rd4);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
RollingD [settDate=, publishingPeriodCommencingTime=, fuelTypeGeneration=G, timeStamp=]
RollingD [settDate=01/04/2020, publishingPeriodCommencingTime=, fuelTypeGeneration=G, timeStamp=]
RollingD [settDate=, publishingPeriodCommencingTime=21:34:26, fuelTypeGeneration=G, timeStamp=]
RollingD [settDate=01/04/2020, publishingPeriodCommencingTime=21:34:26, fuelTypeGeneration=G, timeStamp=01/04/2020 21:34:26]
```

Comment: @ Arvind Kumar Avinash thanks for your reply. I am having trouble integrating this with my API. I have now included that in the question

Comment: @inky - Aren't you able to sort the list of `RollingD` objects based on `timeStamp`? Did I miss anything in understanding your requirement?

Comment: @ Arvind Kumar Avinash The issue is when i pull the data from the API the RollingD objects could be any order.  I have updated my question with how i am polling the API. I believe i have to update this with                                                                                   if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("settDate")) {
       rD = new rollingD(null,null,null);
    bMarks = true;

Comment: @ Arvind Kumar Avinash i no longer have attributes rD.setSettDate(characters.getData());
    bMarks = false;

    }
    if(bLastName) {
  //  System.out.println("publishingPeriodCommencingTime: " + characters.getData());
    rD.setPublishingPeriodCommencingTime(characters.getData());

    bLastName = false;
    }
    if(bNickName) {
   // System.out.println("fuelTypeGeneration: " + characters.getData());
    rD.setFuelTypeGeneration(characters.getData());
    bNickName = false;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The are some miss-concepts on your approach.

Do not need to do any combinations of parameters inside base object(or before adding to).

Just added as you did the objects on List Data Structure

Your issues is maybe: How to process further the list, based on stored-objects
properties.(eg: sorting based on names, date_hours,etc)

Here I strongly advise to search on List methods capabilities.(using a comparator, etc)